# User Dropdown to Select Sorting of Ruby on Rails Index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, web

I have seen things similar to this question, but not exactly what I'm looking for. I did try to find this elsewhere before asking. That being said.

I am creating my first Rails app. I'll make a simple example to demonstrate my problem:

Let's say I have the model Employees.

Each employee has a name and a position.

When I navigate to localhost/Employees/index, I will get a list of the employees. I want that index to be sortable by the user. I want it to have  drop down that allows the user to select what to sort by. If this were PHP, I would just pass the parameter of the user's search preference, and reload the page with a different 'ORDER BY' value, but I can't seem to figure out where to begin with something like this in rails.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey In case you like Jquery then that type of functionality is possible by jquery tool DataTables that make easy for you with lots of more functionality and gives good css for your table in index page.

follow the below link that explain you how to use Datatables

http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast

I hope this helps you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **params** hash is passed by forms to the controller when the user submits a form. An easy way to do this is a separate form for editing search fields. (Apologies if my ERB is wrong, I usually use HAML)

Something like this in your form. It modifies the URL header too.

```
<%= form_tag(params, :method => :get) do %>
  <%= select_tag(:order_by, options_for_select(SET_OF_ORDERS, params[:order_by])) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search with parameters" %>
```

Then in your controller use the **:order_by** param (params[:order_by]) in your find function.

[options_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) is a form helper.

As always, make sure you sanitize the input because users can add anything into a URL request and you don't want SQL injections.